# Metro with jax-ws override endpoint address

Tags: java, jax-ws

I'm creating a webservice client using **Metro** with **jax-ws** and I want to override the endpoint address.

Using the following example from **2.11.1. BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY** I can do that:
http://metro.java.net/guide/How_to_invoke_and_endpoint_by_overriding_endpoint_address_in_the_WSDL.html

```
//Create service and proxy from the generated Service class.
HelloService service = new HelloService();
HelloPort proxy = service.getHelloPort();

((BindingProvider)proxy).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,
                                                    "http://new/endpointaddress");

proxy.sayHello("Hello World!");
```

But I don't understand why I can't use the *service.getHelloPort().sayHello("Hello World!")* instead of *proxy.sayHello("Hello World!")* as the example shows. If I do, the webservice client is using its default endpoint address instead of the one I want to use.

It looks like I'm getting a new instance of *HelloPort* every time I call *getHelloPort()*

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: What is your code? How do you override endpoint address?

Comment: updated with code example. I also got some pointers elswhere.

System.out.println(service.getHelloPort() == service.getHelloPort()) prints out false, so it really looks like I'm getting a new instance for each getHelloPort() call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is little (read: no) difference between these:

```
service.getHelloPort().sayHello("Hello World");
```

and

```
HelloPort proxy = service.getHelloPort();
proxy.sayHello("Hello World!");
```

the service.getHelloPort() call will always return a new proxy/port instance. so any time you modify the request context for a given port object that modification is local to the specific port instance.

generally speaking the port instance you get back is re-usable and thread safe as long as you dont modify the request/response contexts.  for the code sample you posted, it is modifying the request context to set the endpoint address, so it is advisable to get a new port object either every time you need one, or at the very least get a new object for each thread that needs one. (threadlocal is your friend for this)